# create another row from one single row in oracle

Tags: oracle

How to create another row from a single row in oracle?
Suppose, i have a table CALLTEST.

Dataset is like:

```
call_id   PARENT_CALL   OWNER   ACCOUNT_ID    PARENT_CL_OWNER
C3        P3            O4      HCP2           O5
C2        P2            O3      HCP1           O6
```

i have to create an another data from one data each, so total 4 dataset needs to be generated. conditions are:

1. owner field has to be updated with the parent call owner
2. ACCOUNT_ID needs to be updated with null value for the second
       record.
3. call_id will be replaced with _1 value.

dataset would be like this:

```
call_id   PARENT_CALL   OWNER   ACCOUNT_ID    PARENT_CL_OWNER
C3        P3            O5      HCP2           O5
C3_1      P3            O5                     O6
C2        P2            O6      HCP1           O6
C2_1      P2            O6                     O6
```

so please help the exact sql query or the procedure block for achieving this scenerio.

Comment: Did you try writing anything, can you post what have you tried so far?

Comment: i am new in oracle plsql procedure..trying to use union all..but it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT   call_id,
         parent_call,
         parent_cl_owner owner,
         account_id,
         parent_cl_owner
  FROM   calltest
UNION ALL
SELECT   call_id || '_1',
         parent_call,
         parent_cl_owner,
         NULL,
         parent_cl_owner
  FROM   calltest
ORDER BY   call_id
```

Comment: If i have n number of records in my calltest table, so how do i get 2n number of dataset using this UNION ALL function? how this query runs dynamically for multiple number of records?

Comment: because it selects from the callset table twice. hence two rows per each row in callset.